# Run jobs or transformations using carte

Tags: pentaho, kettle

Jobs or transformations store in database repository (mysql).

configure carte

```
    <slave_config>
      <slaveserver>
         <name>master1</name>
         <hostname>localhost</hostname>
         <port>8080</port>
         <master>Y</master>
      </slaveserver>
      <max_log_lines>10000</max_log_lines>
      <max_log_timeout_minutes>1000</max_log_timeout_minutes>
      <object_timeout_minutes>5</object_timeout_minutes>
      <repository>
         <name>10-3-20-66-repository</name>
         <username>admin</username>
         <password>love1314</password>
      </repository>
   </slave_config>
```

Startup carte with this configuration,first run ,no problem. But after one day, remote call is successful, but nothing run.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.getState()
    .setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
             new UsernamePasswordCredentials(carteUserName, cartePassword));
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(carteRunJobUrl+"/?job="+jobpath);
    post.setDoAuthentication(true);
    try {
        return client.executeMethod(post)+"";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }finally{
        post.releaseConnection();
    }
```

Can't it be connected to database repository?

Comment: anyone knows why ? give me a help

Comment: can you please tell me how did you configure this repository with your carte server, i am trying to execute a job with above given configuration and i am getting an error saying "Unable to connect repository in Slave server"

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly fine on file based repository and without any repository as well. I did testing on windows machine.Let me know if you need any inputs regarding this.